# Apple's Scheduled Shutdown & Restart causes error messages

Tags: sleep-wake, shutdown, restart

When I schedule a Shutdown (at night) and schedule a Restart (in the morning), my iMac always reports a "sleep error message" once I've signed in after the morning restart.

The same thing happens when I use a utility like Power Manager (trial). If I manually shut down the computer at night and manually restart in the morning no error messages are generated.

I've rebooted in Diagnostic mode and all is OK. I'm running macOS Catalina 10.15.7.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Here is what I get:   Sleep Wake failure in EFI

Failure code:: 0xffffffff 0x0000001f

Please IGNORE the below stackshot

Date/Time:        2021-12-20 16:49:25 -0600
OS Version:       ??? ??? (Build ???)
Architecture:     x86_64
Report Version:   29

Data Source:      Stackshots
Shared Cache:     0x58a6000 4B1BF041-A1AC-3C93-955E-B9537462927B

Event:            Sleep Wake Failure
Duration:         0.00s
Steps:            1

Time Awake Since Boot: 9s



Process:          swd [302]
Architecture:     x86_64
Footprint:        356 KB

Comment: I can't provif=de the whole error as it's too long

Comment: What is the hardware model of your Mac? (Rather than answering in comments, please edit your question to include the answer to this, along with the **full** sleep-wake failure log, formatted as **code blocks**. Please see Stack Exchange Help if you aren't sure how to do this.)